# Image don't fit perfectly in layout

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-screen-support

I've read pages over pages, but i still have problems with layout for multiple screens. 
I have an image 1080 * 300 pixels that occupy nexus 5 screen horizontally, and is aligned on top of layout (a sort of header). Now if i scale it for xhdpi screens (like galaxy nexus and nexus 4), i don't obtain the same result. by follow scale unit, my 1080 px width image in xxhdpi becomes 720 px image. This dimension fit perfectly for galaxy nexus screen (it's gnexus screen width), but not for nexus 4 that is bigger (768 px), so image don't fill all screen width and i have a blank space on his right. 
If i try to scale image to 768 px width, it fit for nexus 4 but not for gnex.
I've noticed also when i change virtual device for preview, this error from adt console:

```
Displaying it with ', , Locale Language ___Region __, Left To Right, sw384dp, w384dp, h640dp, Normal Screen, Short screen aspect ratio, Portrait Orientation, Normal, Day time, X-High Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Hidden navigation, No navigation, Screen resolution 1280x768, API Level 19'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use 9-patch image if its for background

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom view called [ScaleImageView](https://gist.github.com/gelitenight/7999818) which is written by Maurycy Wojtowicz.

Class is defined like below:

> This view will auto determine the width or height by determining if
>   the height or width is set(exact size or match_parent) and scale the
>   other dimension depending on the images dimension This view also
>   contains an ImageChangeListener which calls changed(boolean isEmpty)
>   once a change has been made to the ImageView

Here is how you are going to implement it.

Create a class named ScaleImageView.java and copy contents of the link above.

In your xml file, create a `ScaleImageView`, just same like `ImageView` (the example I am writing below is for filling screenwidth, and scaling height according to that so there will be no empty spaces on right/left)

```
    <com.project.customview.ScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/scaleImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/file" />
```

If you need to declare and set programmatically in your Activity, it is also the same as using ImageView:

```
imageView = (ScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.scaleImageView);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file);
```